# MongoRepository Unable check condition NumberLong field through JPA @query

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mongorepository

I have JSON document inside the mongo db. with below template

```
  {
    "_id" : "2021_8_4_11_23_57_529",
    "_class" : "fasdf.Reports",
    "taskReports" : [ 
        {
         "taskStatus" : true,
          ...
        }
    ], 
    "cycleId" : NumberLong(1628076200950),
    "cycleSequence" : "1 of 9",
    "imageInReport" : false, 
  }
```

My JPA MongoRepository, I write the query as below,

```
@Query(value = "{'cycleId':?0, 'taskReports.taskStatus':?1}")
public List<Reports> findAllReports(Long cycleId, boolean taskStatus,PageRequest request)
```

When I try find records by any NumberLong fields I am getting empty reports. I logged the query but it seems fine, because its working fine in mongo db shell. Need help/suggestion to get reports if give values matches to cycleId.

Mongo query trace:

```
{ "cycleId" : 1628076200950 , "taskReports.taskStatus" : true}
```

Comment: what is the "Reports " class the return Type here in your repository method?

As i see the findALLReports() - query returns the list<>  .

Comment: @Luica your right. my return type is list and method name used findAllReports. Is it fine if i use any text after findAll<anyText>

Comment: that is fine.  i believe how your query converts to NumberLong may be the issue here.
What Database query works for you and what is the return type for cycleId you are getting?
From the mongo document i can see these are legacy data types supported by mongoshell